# struct, the 'Star' operator and what this means?

Tags: c++, operators

I am not a C++ man, I wonder if someone can explain why the * Operator is used in the struct in terms of C#?

```
#define TIM1_BASE            (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x4400)
#define TIM1               ((TIM_TypeDef *) TIM1_BASE)

typedef struct
{
 __IO uint16_t CR1;

} TIM_TypeDef;
```

For example, does TIM1 become a Class Instance? What does the * operator do in this code?

**EDIT**
How would this look in C#?

**EDIT** What a negative response I have had from people. Sad!!! Is it not the case that this is what 'StackOverFlow' is all about? Some, IMHO, are FUBAR!!!

In C# this is what I get to my Question:

```
private static unsafe TIM_TypeDef* TIM1 = ((TIM_TypeDef*) TIM1_BASE);
```

TIM1 is a TIM_TypeDef Pointer. TIM_TypeDef is a struct, similar to a class. Thanks to the existing answers but they really did not answer my question directly.

Comment: I'm not sure this is C++. My guess would be that the `*` operator does what it always does, defines a pointer.

Comment: @keyser That's not what it always does. It can also do multiplication and dereferencing.

Comment: @PolymorphicPotato I'm well aware. I meant in this context.

Comment: Besides, `*` here does pretty much the same as it does in C#.

Comment: How is your struct involved in this?

Comment: I don't know, its the only 'TIM_TypeDef' I can find in the code.

Comment: But that's just a type. A type that happens to be used with the `*` operator. It's not in any way related to your question. It could just as easily have been `int`. You might want to read up on basic C/C++ with simpler examples. This code looks somewhat advanced.

Comment: @keyser I have a need to try to understand this code. I have done some reading already and there is no real explanation for this example. Thus the question.

Comment: I assure you, there are explanations. Just don't rush it :p My advice would be to look for code that makes use of `TIM1` and `TIM1_BASE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` operator is not actually applied to anything in your example.

Here `((TIM_TypeDef *) TIM1_BASE)` we see `TIM1_BASE` being cast to `TIM_TypeDef *`.  The `*` signifies that the type is a pointer type.  `TIM_TypeDef *` means pointer to `TIM_TypeDef`.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is part of the type: `TIM_TypeDef *`, that is: a pointer to `TIM_TypeDef`.

`(Type) value` is the "C style" *cast*, a way to convert from one type to another.

Answer (score 1):

In types a trailing `*` denotes pointer types. That is for any type `T`, `T*` is the type "pointer to T". So `TIM_TypeDef*` is the type "pointer to a `TIM_TypeDef`" where `TIM_TypeDef` is a type defined elsewhere.

And of course `((T) exp)` is a cast to `T`.

Comment: So TIM1 becomes a TIM_TypeDef Type? What does TIM1 become? If this was put into an array for example.

Answer (score -1):

The three answers from, sepp2K, Karoly and Robert are very good answers but I was wanting more descriptive answers.

So, true to fashion and after a rather negative response from some people, I built a better mouse trap.

The entire code can be found here: http://ghiopensource.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DeviceCode/Targets/Native/STM32F4/DeviceCode/stm32f4xx.h

C++ Code snippet:

```
typedef struct
{
__IO uint32_t MODER;    /*!< GPIO port mode register,               Address offset: 0x00      */
__IO uint32_t OTYPER;   /*!< GPIO port output type register,        Address offset: 0x04      */
__IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;  /*!< GPIO port output speed register,       Address offset: 0x08      */
__IO uint32_t PUPDR;    /*!< GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register,  Address offset: 0x0C      */
__IO uint32_t IDR;      /*!< GPIO port input data register,         Address offset: 0x10      */
__IO uint32_t ODR;      /*!< GPIO port output data register,        Address offset: 0x14      */
__IO uint16_t BSRRL;    /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset low register,  Address offset: 0x18      */
__IO uint16_t BSRRH;    /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset high register, Address offset: 0x1A      */
__IO uint32_t LCKR;     /*!< GPIO port configuration lock register, Address offset: 0x1C      */
__IO uint32_t AFR[2];   /*!< GPIO alternate function registers,     Address offset: 0x20-0x24 */
} GPIO_TypeDef;

....

#define GPIOA               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOA_BASE)
#define GPIOB               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOB_BASE)
#define GPIOC               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOC_BASE)
#define GPIOD               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOD_BASE)
#define GPIOE               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOE_BASE)
#define GPIOF               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOF_BASE)
#define GPIOG               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOG_BASE)
#define GPIOH               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOH_BASE)
#define GPIOI               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOI_BASE)
....

/*!< AHB1 peripherals */
#define GPIOA_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0000)
#define GPIOB_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0400)
#define GPIOC_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0800)
#define GPIOD_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0C00)
#define GPIOE_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x1000)
#define GPIOF_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x1400)
#define GPIOG_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x1800)
#define GPIOH_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x1C00)
#define GPIOI_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x2000)

....


/******************************************************************************/
/*                                                                            */
/*                            General Purpose I/O                             */
/*                                                                            */
/******************************************************************************/
/******************  Bits definition for GPIO_MODER register  *****************/
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER0                    ((uint32_t)0x00000003)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER0_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00000001)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER0_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00000002)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER1                    ((uint32_t)0x0000000C)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER1_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00000004)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER1_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00000008)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER2                    ((uint32_t)0x00000030)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER2_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00000010)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER2_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00000020)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER3                    ((uint32_t)0x000000C0)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER3_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00000040)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER3_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00000080)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER4                    ((uint32_t)0x00000300)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER4_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00000100)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER4_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00000200)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER5                    ((uint32_t)0x00000C00)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER5_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00000400)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER5_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00000800)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER6                    ((uint32_t)0x00003000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER6_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00001000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER6_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00002000)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER7                    ((uint32_t)0x0000C000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER7_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00004000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER7_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00008000)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER8                    ((uint32_t)0x00030000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER8_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00010000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER8_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00020000)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER9                    ((uint32_t)0x000C0000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER9_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00040000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER9_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00080000)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER10                   ((uint32_t)0x00300000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER10_0                 ((uint32_t)0x00100000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER10_1                 ((uint32_t)0x00200000)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER11                   ((uint32_t)0x00C00000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER11_0                 ((uint32_t)0x00400000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER11_1                 ((uint32_t)0x00800000)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER12                   ((uint32_t)0x03000000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER12_0                 ((uint32_t)0x01000000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER12_1                 ((uint32_t)0x02000000)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER13                   ((uint32_t)0x0C000000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER13_0                 ((uint32_t)0x04000000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER13_1                 ((uint32_t)0x08000000)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER14                   ((uint32_t)0x30000000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER14_0                 ((uint32_t)0x10000000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER14_1                 ((uint32_t)0x20000000)

#define GPIO_MODER_MODER15                   ((uint32_t)0xC0000000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER15_0                 ((uint32_t)0x40000000)
#define GPIO_MODER_MODER15_1                 ((uint32_t)0x80000000)

/******************  Bits definition for GPIO_OTYPER register  ****************/
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_0                     ((uint32_t)0x00000001)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_1                     ((uint32_t)0x00000002)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_2                     ((uint32_t)0x00000004)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_3                     ((uint32_t)0x00000008)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_4                     ((uint32_t)0x00000010)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_5                     ((uint32_t)0x00000020)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_6                     ((uint32_t)0x00000040)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_7                     ((uint32_t)0x00000080)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_8                     ((uint32_t)0x00000100)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_9                     ((uint32_t)0x00000200)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_10                    ((uint32_t)0x00000400)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_11                    ((uint32_t)0x00000800)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_12                    ((uint32_t)0x00001000)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_13                    ((uint32_t)0x00002000)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_14                    ((uint32_t)0x00004000)
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OT_15                    ((uint32_t)0x00008000)

/******************  Bits definition for GPIO_OSPEEDR register  ***************/
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR0               ((uint32_t)0x00000003)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR0_0             ((uint32_t)0x00000001)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR0_1             ((uint32_t)0x00000002)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR1               ((uint32_t)0x0000000C)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR1_0             ((uint32_t)0x00000004)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR1_1             ((uint32_t)0x00000008)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR2               ((uint32_t)0x00000030)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR2_0             ((uint32_t)0x00000010)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR2_1             ((uint32_t)0x00000020)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR3               ((uint32_t)0x000000C0)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR3_0             ((uint32_t)0x00000040)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR3_1             ((uint32_t)0x00000080)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR4               ((uint32_t)0x00000300)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR4_0             ((uint32_t)0x00000100)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR4_1             ((uint32_t)0x00000200)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR5               ((uint32_t)0x00000C00)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR5_0             ((uint32_t)0x00000400)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR5_1             ((uint32_t)0x00000800)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR6               ((uint32_t)0x00003000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR6_0             ((uint32_t)0x00001000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR6_1             ((uint32_t)0x00002000)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR7               ((uint32_t)0x0000C000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR7_0             ((uint32_t)0x00004000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR7_1             ((uint32_t)0x00008000)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR8               ((uint32_t)0x00030000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR8_0             ((uint32_t)0x00010000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR8_1             ((uint32_t)0x00020000)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR9               ((uint32_t)0x000C0000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR9_0             ((uint32_t)0x00040000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR9_1             ((uint32_t)0x00080000)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR10              ((uint32_t)0x00300000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR10_0            ((uint32_t)0x00100000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR10_1            ((uint32_t)0x00200000)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR11              ((uint32_t)0x00C00000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR11_0            ((uint32_t)0x00400000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR11_1            ((uint32_t)0x00800000)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR12              ((uint32_t)0x03000000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR12_0            ((uint32_t)0x01000000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR12_1            ((uint32_t)0x02000000)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR13              ((uint32_t)0x0C000000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR13_0            ((uint32_t)0x04000000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR13_1            ((uint32_t)0x08000000)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR14              ((uint32_t)0x30000000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR14_0            ((uint32_t)0x10000000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR14_1            ((uint32_t)0x20000000)

#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR15              ((uint32_t)0xC0000000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR15_0            ((uint32_t)0x40000000)
#define GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR15_1            ((uint32_t)0x80000000)

/******************  Bits definition for GPIO_PUPDR register  *****************/
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR0                    ((uint32_t)0x00000003)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR0_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00000001)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR0_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00000002)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR1                    ((uint32_t)0x0000000C)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR1_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00000004)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR1_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00000008)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR2                    ((uint32_t)0x00000030)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR2_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00000010)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR2_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00000020)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR3                    ((uint32_t)0x000000C0)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR3_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00000040)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR3_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00000080)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR4                    ((uint32_t)0x00000300)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR4_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00000100)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR4_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00000200)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR5                    ((uint32_t)0x00000C00)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR5_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00000400)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR5_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00000800)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR6                    ((uint32_t)0x00003000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR6_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00001000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR6_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00002000)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR7                    ((uint32_t)0x0000C000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR7_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00004000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR7_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00008000)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR8                    ((uint32_t)0x00030000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR8_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00010000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR8_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00020000)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR9                    ((uint32_t)0x000C0000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR9_0                  ((uint32_t)0x00040000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR9_1                  ((uint32_t)0x00080000)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR10                   ((uint32_t)0x00300000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR10_0                 ((uint32_t)0x00100000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR10_1                 ((uint32_t)0x00200000)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR11                   ((uint32_t)0x00C00000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR11_0                 ((uint32_t)0x00400000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR11_1                 ((uint32_t)0x00800000)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR12                   ((uint32_t)0x03000000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR12_0                 ((uint32_t)0x01000000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR12_1                 ((uint32_t)0x02000000)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR13                   ((uint32_t)0x0C000000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR13_0                 ((uint32_t)0x04000000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR13_1                 ((uint32_t)0x08000000)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR14                   ((uint32_t)0x30000000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR14_0                 ((uint32_t)0x10000000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR14_1                 ((uint32_t)0x20000000)

#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR15                   ((uint32_t)0xC0000000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR15_0                 ((uint32_t)0x40000000)
#define GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR15_1                 ((uint32_t)0x80000000)

/******************  Bits definition for GPIO_IDR register  *******************/
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_0                       ((uint32_t)0x00000001)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_1                       ((uint32_t)0x00000002)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_2                       ((uint32_t)0x00000004)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_3                       ((uint32_t)0x00000008)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_4                       ((uint32_t)0x00000010)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_5                       ((uint32_t)0x00000020)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_6                       ((uint32_t)0x00000040)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_7                       ((uint32_t)0x00000080)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_8                       ((uint32_t)0x00000100)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_9                       ((uint32_t)0x00000200)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_10                      ((uint32_t)0x00000400)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_11                      ((uint32_t)0x00000800)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_12                      ((uint32_t)0x00001000)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_13                      ((uint32_t)0x00002000)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_14                      ((uint32_t)0x00004000)
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR_15                      ((uint32_t)0x00008000)
/* Old GPIO_IDR register bits definition, maintained for legacy purpose */
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_0                    GPIO_IDR_IDR_0
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_1                    GPIO_IDR_IDR_1
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_2                    GPIO_IDR_IDR_2
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_3                    GPIO_IDR_IDR_3
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_4                    GPIO_IDR_IDR_4
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_5                    GPIO_IDR_IDR_5
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_6                    GPIO_IDR_IDR_6
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_7                    GPIO_IDR_IDR_7
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_8                    GPIO_IDR_IDR_8
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_9                    GPIO_IDR_IDR_9
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_10                   GPIO_IDR_IDR_10
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_11                   GPIO_IDR_IDR_11
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_12                   GPIO_IDR_IDR_12
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_13                   GPIO_IDR_IDR_13
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_14                   GPIO_IDR_IDR_14
#define GPIO_OTYPER_IDR_15                   GPIO_IDR_IDR_15

/******************  Bits definition for GPIO_ODR register  *******************/
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_0                       ((uint32_t)0x00000001)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_1                       ((uint32_t)0x00000002)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_2                       ((uint32_t)0x00000004)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_3                       ((uint32_t)0x00000008)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_4                       ((uint32_t)0x00000010)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_5                       ((uint32_t)0x00000020)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_6                       ((uint32_t)0x00000040)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_7                       ((uint32_t)0x00000080)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_8                       ((uint32_t)0x00000100)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_9                       ((uint32_t)0x00000200)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_10                      ((uint32_t)0x00000400)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_11                      ((uint32_t)0x00000800)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_12                      ((uint32_t)0x00001000)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_13                      ((uint32_t)0x00002000)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_14                      ((uint32_t)0x00004000)
#define GPIO_ODR_ODR_15                      ((uint32_t)0x00008000)
/* Old GPIO_ODR register bits definition, maintained for legacy purpose */
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_0                    GPIO_ODR_ODR_0
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_1                    GPIO_ODR_ODR_1
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_2                    GPIO_ODR_ODR_2
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_3                    GPIO_ODR_ODR_3
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_4                    GPIO_ODR_ODR_4
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_5                    GPIO_ODR_ODR_5
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_6                    GPIO_ODR_ODR_6
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_7                    GPIO_ODR_ODR_7
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_8                    GPIO_ODR_ODR_8
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_9                    GPIO_ODR_ODR_9
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_10                   GPIO_ODR_ODR_10
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_11                   GPIO_ODR_ODR_11
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_12                   GPIO_ODR_ODR_12
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_13                   GPIO_ODR_ODR_13
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_14                   GPIO_ODR_ODR_14
#define GPIO_OTYPER_ODR_15                   GPIO_ODR_ODR_15

/******************  Bits definition for GPIO_BSRR register  ******************/
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_0                       ((uint32_t)0x00000001)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_1                       ((uint32_t)0x00000002)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_2                       ((uint32_t)0x00000004)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_3                       ((uint32_t)0x00000008)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_4                       ((uint32_t)0x00000010)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_5                       ((uint32_t)0x00000020)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_6                       ((uint32_t)0x00000040)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_7                       ((uint32_t)0x00000080)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_8                       ((uint32_t)0x00000100)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_9                       ((uint32_t)0x00000200)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_10                      ((uint32_t)0x00000400)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_11                      ((uint32_t)0x00000800)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_12                      ((uint32_t)0x00001000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_13                      ((uint32_t)0x00002000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_14                      ((uint32_t)0x00004000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BS_15                      ((uint32_t)0x00008000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_0                       ((uint32_t)0x00010000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_1                       ((uint32_t)0x00020000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_2                       ((uint32_t)0x00040000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_3                       ((uint32_t)0x00080000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_4                       ((uint32_t)0x00100000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_5                       ((uint32_t)0x00200000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_6                       ((uint32_t)0x00400000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_7                       ((uint32_t)0x00800000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_8                       ((uint32_t)0x01000000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_9                       ((uint32_t)0x02000000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_10                      ((uint32_t)0x04000000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_11                      ((uint32_t)0x08000000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_12                      ((uint32_t)0x10000000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_13                      ((uint32_t)0x20000000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_14                      ((uint32_t)0x40000000)
#define GPIO_BSRR_BR_15                      ((uint32_t)0x80000000)

....
```

**SO** My question: "I wonder if someone can explain why the * Operator is used in the struct in terms of C#" **HERE IT IS IN C#**:

```
public sealed class GPIO
{
#region Private's...

private UInt32 _MODER = 0x00;
private UInt32 _OTYPER = 0x04;
private UInt32 _OSPEEDR = 0x08;
private UInt32 _PUPDR = 0x0C;
private UInt32 _IDR = 0x10;
private UInt32 _ODR = 0x14;
private UInt32 _BSRRL = 0x18;
private UInt32 _BSRRH = 0x1A;
private UInt32 _LCKR = 0x1C;
// private UInt32 AFR[2] = 0x20-0x24;

#endregion

#region Properties...

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port mode register, Address offset: 0x00
/// </summary>
public UInt32 MODER { get { return _MODER; } set { _MODER = value; } }  

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port output type register, Address offset: 0x04
/// </summary>
public UInt32 OTYPER { get { return _OTYPER; } set { _OTYPER = value; } } 

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port output speed register, Address offset: 0x08
/// </summary>
public UInt32 OSPEEDR { get { return _OSPEEDR; } set { _OSPEEDR = value; } } 

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register, Address offset: 0x0C
/// </summary>
public UInt32 PUPDR { get { return _PUPDR; } set { _PUPDR = value; } }  

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port input data register, Address offset: 0x10 
/// </summary>
public UInt32 IDR { get { return _IDR; } set { _IDR = value; } }  

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port output data register, Address offset: 0x14
/// </summary>
public UInt32 ODR { get { return _ODR; } set { _ODR = value; } } 

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port bit set/reset low register, Address offset: 0x18
/// </summary>
public UInt32 BSRRL { get { return _BSRRL; } set { _BSRRL = value; } } 

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port bit set/reset high register, Address offset: 0x1A
/// </summary>
public UInt32 BSRRH { get { return _BSRRH; } set { _BSRRH = value; } } 

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port configuration lock register, Address offset: 0x1C
/// </summary>
public UInt32 LCKR { get { return _LCKR; } set { _LCKR = value; } }  

/// <summary>
/// GPIO alternate function registers, Address offset: 0x20-0x24
/// </summary>
// public UInt32 AFR[2] { get { return _AFR; } set { _AFR = value; } }    

#endregion

#region Registers...

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port mode register, Address offset: 0x00
/// </summary>
public Register MODER_Register;

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port output type register, Address offset: 0x04
/// </summary>
public Register OTYPER_Register;

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port output speed register, Address offset: 0x08
/// </summary>
public Register OSPEEDR_Register;

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register, Address offset: 0x0C
/// </summary>
public Register PUPDR_Register;

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port input data register, Address offset: 0x10 
/// </summary>
public Register IDR_Register;

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port output data register, Address offset: 0x14
/// </summary>
public Register ODR_Register;

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port bit set/reset low register, Address offset: 0x18
/// </summary>
public Register BSRRL_Register;

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port bit set/reset high register, Address offset: 0x1A
/// </summary>
public Register BSRRH_Register;

/// <summary>
/// GPIO port configuration lock register, Address offset: 0x1C
/// </summary>
public Register LCKR_Register;

/// <summary>
/// GPIO alternate function registers, Address offset: 0x20-0x24
/// </summary>
// public Register AFR[2];    

#endregion

/// <summary>
/// GPIOA. Class Type for defining the GPIOA Register Types...
/// </summary>
public static GPIO GPIOA = new GPIO(STM32F4xx.GPIOA_BASE);

/// <summary>
/// GPIOB. Class Type for defining the GPIOB Register Types...
/// </summary>
public static GPIO GPIOB = new GPIO(STM32F4xx.GPIOB_BASE);

public GPIO(UInt32 GPIOx_BASE)
{
MODER_Register = new Register(GPIOx_BASE + MODER);
OTYPER_Register = new Register(GPIOx_BASE + OTYPER);
OSPEEDR_Register = new Register(GPIOx_BASE + OSPEEDR);
PUPDR_Register = new Register(GPIOx_BASE + PUPDR);
IDR_Register = new Register(GPIOx_BASE + IDR);
ODR_Register = new Register(GPIOx_BASE + ODR);
BSRRL_Register = new Register(GPIOx_BASE + BSRRL);
BSRRH_Register = new Register(GPIOx_BASE + BSRRH);
LCKR_Register = new Register(GPIOx_BASE + LCKR); 
}
}
```

So you can see, 'GPIO_TypeDef' that is declared as a struct above, I have configured as a class 'GPIO' in my C# Code. I have set the Registers as public but the UInt32's as private and just use Properties to access them. The * Operator, like the answers pointed out is a pointer. To get around using unsafe code in my edit, in my Question I have set the public Properties and Registers to be based on the GPIOx_BASE UInt.

```
public static class STM32F4xx
{
public static uint GPIOA_BASE = (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0000);
}
```

Rather elegantly I can simply use the following code to se the Register Value:

```
GPIO.GPIOA.MODER_Register.SetBits(3 << 8);
```

I have heard people say C++ is a superior Language, but I must say to read it if you're not familiar with it is MUMBOJUMBO!!!

I do however understand C++ a little more after the experience.